# PHP cUrl: internal server error on webspace but not on homeserver

Tags: php, apache, curl, internal-server-error

i have the following script:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$cSession = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.de");
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$result = curl_exec($cSession);

if(!$result) {
  echo curl_error($cSession);
} else {
  echo $result;
}

curl_close($cSession);

?>
```

All i want to do is to relay an api that lies on my homeserver to my webspace (dyndns is not an option for sll reasons). So google.de is just a placeholder here.

When i try the script on my homeserver (apache2) all works fine. The cUrl is executed and i can echo the result. If i upload the script to my webspace (one.com) then i get an internal server error without any additional helpful information. The webspace supports php and cUrl:

[image: phpinfo()]

Any helpful information where i could find a solution would be nice. Thank you!

Comment: Check error logs

Comment: unfortunately i don't have access to the logs.

Comment: Request for error logs from provider